# cloudformation with API Gateway: Using two required path parameters fails with SAM build but it works with sam local start-api

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I've in my .yaml file some lambdas connected to my API Gateway like this (I changed this a little bit in order to use different names in this example)

```yaml
  SAMPLEFUNCTION:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub SAMPLE-API-${Env}-SAMPLE
      CodeUri: ../src
      Handler: sample.lambdaHandler
      Timeout: 900
      MemorySize: 512
      Events:
        Organization:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
            Path: /admin/test/{organization_id}/sample/{section_id}
            Method: delete
            RequestParameters:
              method.request.path.organization_id: true
              method.request.path.section_id: true
```

the problem is that this endpoints using two request parameters fails when I try to do the sam build

```
 Resource with id
[SAMPLEFUNCTION] is invalid. Type of
property 'RequestParameters' is invalid
```

I've checked that the yaml indentation is OK, that the RequestParameters must be inside Properties and in the right format, I don't know why this doesn't work and even worse, why it works locally but it can't be deployed

any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: How did it go? Did you change `RequestParameters` to list as advised?

Comment: @Marcin no, neither change this to list nor use as objects works for me, at the end the solution was more simple, just remove the RequestParameters...SAM notices the braces in the path and automatically handle these as required parameters

Answer (score 0):

[Example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-requestparameter.html#sam-property-function-requestparameter--examples) shows that `RequestParameters` is a list, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

changing this to list instead of object didn't work, at least for me, at the end the solution was pretty simple, just remove the RequestParameters, SAM notices that your path includes braces and automatically handles these as required parameters

```
Path: /admin/test/{organization_id}/sample/{section_id}
Method: delete
```